# Django can't find angular file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have following html file

```
<html>
<head>
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "app.js" %}"/></script>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
{% verbatim foo %}
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)">^</span>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
      - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
      <br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
{% endverbatim foo %}
</html>
```

And this is my angularjs file

```
'use strict'

angular.module('flapperNews', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

  $scope.posts = [];

  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if($scope.title === '') { return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
      upvotes: 0
    });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
  };

  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    post.upvotes += 1;
  };

}]);
```

The template is located in mysite/templates and the angular file is located in mysite/static. When I have a look at the development server I receive following output when requesting the page:

```
[10/Jul/2015 09:23:09]"GET /guides/ HTTP/1.1" 200 861
[10/Jul/2015 09:23:09]"GET /static/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1632
```

And when I have a look at the developer console from firefox I receive a Error: [$injector:modulerr]. Do you guys know why the usage of my app.js is not working?

Edit: Static files in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/mysite/static/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should set the [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) in you project settings. This should do the trick:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

It is not enough to just set the [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-url) (this is the url you will be serving the static files) and [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-root) (this is the location on your server/system your application will store the static files when you run `manage.py collectstatic`).

By default django searches for static files using `AppDirectoriesFinder` (which searches for static files in the app directories) and `FileSystemFinder` (which searches the directories that are in `STATICFILES_DIRS`)

If the static file settings are still not clear, take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-files).

Comment: The file is found now but I receive the error "angular is not defined"

Comment: I updated my answer to also explain what the differnt static settings do ;)

Comment: That is due to the fact that you load your `app.js` before angular. When you put the `script`-tag in which you load `app.js` after the angular `script`-tag it should probably work.

Comment: yeah I just realized that too. But still thank you for the comment, it was right :P